# How to compress video file using gzip in MVC?

Tags: c#, video, model-view-controller, compression, gzip

Trying to compress video using gzip , video get compressed and saved in database but when i try to play using video tag then it dosen't work.

when i try to play video manually then also it doesn't play in VLC or any media player.

My objective is to upload a video and compress it before it get save into database. Video may be of any format which are supported by video tag.

```
FileStream compressedFileStream;
compressedFileStream = new FileStream(fullPath1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
byte[] buffer = new byte[compressedFileStream.Length];
int count = compressedFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
if (count != buffer.Length)
{
    compressedFileStream.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Test Failed: Unable to read data from file");
    //return;
}
compressedFileStream.Close();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
GZipStream compressedzipStream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionLevel.Optimal, true);
compressedzipStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
// Close the stream.
compressedzipStream.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Original size: {0}, Compressed size: {1}", buffer.Length, ms.Length);
Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(fileDirectory1), System.IO.File.Delete);
FileStream fileaftrcmprsn = new FileStream(fullPath1, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
ms.WriteTo(fileaftrcmprsn);                         
fileaftrcmprsn.Close();
```

Comment: Kindly recommend any alternate way to compress video..

Comment: And do not store it in databse.

Comment: You cannot compress video data. If you want smaller video files, you must encode them using a lower bitrate and/or lower resolution.